# how to save document with range on active sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i use this code but isn't working.

```
FN = Sheets("COA").Range("C7") & "_" & Sheets("COA").Range("B1") & "_" & Sheets("COA").Range("C6")
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I50").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I50").SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Sadirun\Documents\" & FN, FileFormat:=51
```

i've tried a several ways, but it isn't working

Comment: You've posted enough here to know that "isn't working" is not a very useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code.

Comment: I think after your copy code, you may want to create a new workbook, then paste the copied range to this new workbook. Then save the new workbook. Then close the new workbook. Something like this : `With Workbooks.Add` ... next line : `.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlAll)` ... next line `.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Sadirun\Documents\" & FN, FileFormat:=51` ... next line `.Close SaveChanges:=False` ... next line `end with`. Step run the code to see how it happen.

Comment: that code will paste all in sheet. but i want copy paste with range a1:i50

Answer (score 0):

### Export a Range to a New Workbook

```vb
Sub ExportRange()

    Dim dPath As String: dPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.ActiveSheet
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:I50")
    
    Dim dFileName As String
    With swb.Sheets("COA")
        dFileName = CStr(.Range("C7").Value) & "_" & CStr(.Range("B1").Value) _
            & "_" & CStr(.Range("C6").Value)
    End With
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(srg.Address)
    
    srg.Rows(1).Copy
    drg.Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    drg.Cells(1).Select
    
    Dim sCell As Range, r As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Columns(1).Cells
        r = r + 1
        drg.Rows(r).RowHeight = sCell.RowHeight
    Next sCell

    srg.Copy drg
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dPath & dFileName ' , FileFormat:=51 ' default
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox "Range Exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```